# Excel - Count only instances of unique values in two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unique, multiple-columns

Please see image below, I am looking to populate cells G8-G12 with a value of how many times the day appears in Column B and has a unique date in Column A. So as an example, Wednesday would count 2 as it appears on 28/02/2024 and 06/03/2024. 

How do I do this?

I've tried SUMPRODUCT and COUNTIFS but not managed to get what I wanted, for example I used

```
(=SUMPRODUCT((1/COUNTIFS(A2:A12,A2:A12,B2:B12,F8)))
```

in cell G8 but it's incorrect.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: how about a pivot table on Day with count of Dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what Older versions of Excel need to use:

[image]

---

```
=SUMPRODUCT((F8=B$2:B$12)/(COUNTIFS(B$2:B$12,B$2:B$12,A$2:A$12,A$2:A$12)))
```

---

Or, Using Newer Versions of Excel:

[image]

---

```
=SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER(A$2:A$12,F8=B$2:B$12))<>""))
```

---

Also using `Pivot Table` to get unique distinct count one needs to add the data in the `Data Model` to apply the summarization with `Distinct Counts` -- the feature is available in `Windows Excel 2013+` and `Excel 365 (Windows)`

[image]

---

To use follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table_1`

---

- Select some cell in your data and click on `Insert` Tab -> Click on `Pivot Table` --> The `Table/Range` will shows as `Table_1`, Click on `New Worksheet` or `Existing Worksheet` as per your choice, --> If latter select the cell location and click on `Add this data the Data Model`.

---

- On right `Pivot Table` Fields Pane appears, place the `Day` in `Rows` Area and `Date` in `Values` area,

---

- Click on the values in the pivot table, right click --> `Summarize Values By` --> `Distinct Count`.

[image]

---

- Note that in the pivot table i have used a custom sorting order, which one can apply by using a custom lists in the file options menu.

---

Comment: @topstuff btw with `Pivot Table` you need to add the data in the data model and then use `Distinct Counts` for summarization, i have mentioned all the steps

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do a pivot-table with Day as row and Date as value then count quantity [image]